# extracting rows from two tables in php and sql

Tags: php, sql

I have two tables `properties` and `buildings`. I want to extract rows from the `buildings` table according to a criteria.

I have put these buildings ids in a variable, as below:

```
$buildings = "1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10"
```

I am trying to access the properties according to the above list.

```
SELECT * FROM properties WHERE BUILDING_ID IN ('{$buildings}')
```

but I am not getting the desired result. How can I get the desired result? Is this the right approach?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do something like:

```
$buildings = "1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10";
$buildingIDs = explode(",", $buildings);

$buildingQueries = array();
foreach ($buildingIDs as $buildingID) {
  $buildingQueries[] = "BUILDING_ID = " . $buildingID;
}

$query = "SELECT * FROM properties WHERE " . implode(" OR ", $buildingQueries);
```

That will let you take advantage of indexes, and allow for variable IDs.

Warning: you should look into mysqli or PDO, and move away from the soon to be deprecated mysql library

Answer (score 4):

Remove the single quotes (and optionally the braces).

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM properties WHERE BUILDING_ID IN ($buildings)"
```

Note that `IN` is not always the most efficient as it can't use indexes - if you can use [`BETWEEN`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/comparison-operators.html#operator_between) instead, you may get better performance on a large dataset. But for smaller datasets, `IN` is fine.

Comment: i have a big list, it can be 1000 values in the buildings variable. i tried after rmoving quotes and brace. but it keeps busy and not showing any result.

Comment: That's good - "keeps busy" is the key here as it means the query is working. As I said in the answer, "IN" is not efficient as it can't use indexes so it parses the entire database 1000 times. Ouch. You may  want to find a better way of getting the data (using an indexed field), or break into smaller chunks.

Comment: 1000 records shouldn't take that long to get - indexed or not - that said, there's ways to improve this

Comment: I totally agree - shouldn't be that long (now I think about it). Probably a case of "more info required" to help speed it up. At least the initial problem should be sorted.